# Why does my score counter always reset?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a game and can't seem to get the score counter to work. The problem is that every time the button is clicked the value of the integer goes back to 0.

```
public void button(View view){
    Integer counter = Integer.valueOf(0);
    counter = counter++;
    final TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    score.setText("Score: " + counter);
}
```

I obviously see why the score goes back to 0 every time but I don't know how to fix it. I'm new with development so some sample code would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use a local variable that you always set to zero; use an instance variable. Also, `counter++` already assigns the incremented value to counter-might want to focus on some java basics before going much further.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Could you show me some sample code?

Comment: There are tons of Android examples that show how to use instance variables--I might suggest looking over one of those. That said, without at least some knowledge of how Java works, Android itself is going to be a pretty tough road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are resetting it.

```
Integer counter = Integer.valueOf(0); // here
counter = counter++;
```

Use it a global variable instead.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    int counter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(...);
        counter = 0; 
    }

public void button(View view){
    counter = counter++;
    final TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    score.setText("Score: " + counter);
}

}
```

Comment: I know why it's resetting, but how would I fix it? I can't just get rid of that line because it's declaring the integer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would vote it up but I can't because I don't have 15 reputation :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's some modified code from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    int counter = 0; // Counter variable.

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
             counter = counter++;
             final TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
             score.setText("Score: " + counter);
         }
     });
 }
```

}

This should do what you want. Hope it helps!

Comment: Are you sure you should be spoon feeding him/her? I am quite sure you should understand variables and their scope before diving into SDKs/APIs.

Comment: You have to start somewhere, right? Having some code to work with might give them a better idea of what they're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to initialize your counter in a more persistent part of your program or even as a global variable. Each time you call your function, you are initializing a **new** counter.

In order to tackle this problem, you should research variable scope.
(Sample link from a Google Search for "Java variable scope".[(1)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm) )